# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know what `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call (<string>, line 6)` means in relation to my specific line of code. I've looked around just about everywhere and I'm not getting anything I understand, simply because I just started learning code yesterday and much of what everyone else has mixed in with their strings of code is confusing.
Here is what I have entered:

```
name = 'Hayley'
print(len(name))

while len(name) < 10:
    print('k')
    len(name) = len(name) + 1
print('Done.')
```

I want the program to add 1 to the length of the name until it isn't less than ten anymore. It starts off at 6 and then increases by 1 until it hits 10 and the program doesn't run anymore.

I'm just trying to practice with loops and using a lot of meaningless things just to practice and make sure it sticks in my head. I'm trying to learn to code for an internship I will work at this summer.

Comment: `len(name)` is a function call. You can't make a string longer by adding to its length, no.

Comment: And no, I don't think your intention is apparent. Please do add your *expected output* to your question.

Comment: Writing useless code is not useful practice. Write programs that actually do things.

Comment: even if it did work  `len(name) = len(name) + 1` makes no sense, start with a tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: for your edit `for _ in range(len(name),10):print("k")`

Comment: You are trying to assign to the result of `len(name)`. You can't, because the result of a function call is not a variable that can hold the result of an expression.

Comment: Thank you, Martijn Pieters and Padriac Cunningham
I understand now

Comment: `len(name)` returns the length of the `name` string. If you make the string longer by adding more characters to it eg `name = name + '.'` then `len(name)` will return a bigger number.

Comment: *"I want the program to add 1 to the length of the name"* - independent of writing code to do this, that clearly makes absolutely no sense. The length of the name is how long the name is.

Answer (score 1):

Better to remember while a beginner,

if there is parantheses(round bracket) in the left side of an assignment, you should check it again and be extra careful.

```
len("arg")
```

is a function called with the argument "arg" and it already returns a value. Therefore cannot be assigned to something, **something can be assigned to it.**

I cannot truly help you because of not knowing exactly what you are trying to do. But what you expected to happen while you tried to increase the length of the string, by using the function to measure the length alone. Study on what you exactly want and you will get closer to the answer, like in all other subjects.

Answer (score 0):

len(name) returns you the length of "Hayley" in your code above. You cannot assign another value to it. Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
>>> name = "Hayley"
>>> x = len(name)
>>> print(x)

6

In [2]:

>>> while x < 10:
>>>    print('k')
>>>    x += 1
>>> print('Done.')

k
k
k
k
Done.
```